# Cannot Generate method stub Visual Studio 2015 + Resharper 9

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I just upgraded Visual Studio to 2015 Pro version and installed resharper 9.0.
Now, when i create some method i can't generate method stub like shown [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/01/01/generate-method-stubs-using-shortcut-key-in-visual-studio/)

Visual Studio 2015 don't show solutions for generating method stub. And even resharper doesn't show lightbulb on the left.

[image]

Another thing:

When i try to add new variable to method, same thing - resharper doesn't suggest anything - no lightbulb on the left.

[image]

Is there some configuration i'm missing or some features turned off?

UPDATE:
Well, i found one little check, that helped with first problem.
Resharper options -> Code Inspection -> Settings -> Uncheck "Do not show Visual Studio bulb"

Comment: Yes, "Generate Method Stub" is missing for me too.  Even when I enable the lightbulb, it's not listed.  One of the most useful functions in VS is gone.

Comment: @Muno Did you try with Ctrl + . ? Dialog, same as that of _lightbulb_ shoud show up.

Answer (score 1):

You may have solved this problem by now though.

I also have encountered this and I just hover my mouse onto the symbol 
ex. (getUser)

```
string user = getUser();
```

a yellow light bulb should pop up with a drop down arrow next to it,click the down arrow then choose "Generate method Global.getUser"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like ReSharper 9.0 is not fully supported in VS2015... :(

Take a look: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/22454

Comment: The link is dead now?